# Does SWI prolog support DCTGs?

Tags: prolog

I found out about DCTGs from here: http://cmsmcq.com/2004/lgintro.html#id2631925, and I can't for the life of me get it working with SWI prolog, or even find any documentation at all on it.

Answer (score 1):

I got dctg.tgz from http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/lang/prolog/code/syntax/dctg/.

There are problems, since such code was written with the **old** operator precedences, ranging from 1 to 255, while currently all systems range from 1 to 1200. Here is a patched dctg.pl, that - at least - you can consult without errors, and then allows

```
?- % /home/carlo/prolog/dctg/dctg compiled 0.01 sec, 37 clauses
dctg_reconsult('dctgtest.pl').
true .
```

disclaimer: the corrections are just based on syntax errors and warnings reported from the original dctg.pl

```
% patched dctg.pl, answering http://stackoverflow.com/q/32701614/874024

/*  DCTG.PL  */

/*  Shelved on 21st August 1990.  */


/*
This file defines a DCTG translator as described in ...

It makes a few changes ... operator prec ... from

It also defines the predicate dctg_reconsult, for loading
grammars from file. The specification follows. */


/*  dctg_reconsult( File+ ):
        File: a filename (atom).
    Loads the DCTG grammar in File, converting it to internal
    form useable by the parser.

    dctg_reconsult expects the following terms in its file:
        ?- (X)                  Call X, and go on to the next term.
        :- (X)                  Call X, and go on to the next term.
        X::=Y                   Translate as a DCTG clause, and assert
                                the corresponding Prolog.
        X:-Y                    Assert.
        Any other term X.       Assert.

    dctg_reconsult acts like ordinary reconsult in its dealings with
    repeated clauses. If it meets a clause C with functor and arity
    F,A, then it will always assert the clause. It will delete
    all other clauses for the same functor and arity, provided that
    they did not immediately precede the current one C.

    This applies both to ordinary Prolog clauses, and to DCTG clauses.
*/
:- op( 1045, yfx, ^^ ).
:- op( 1050, xfx, ::= ).
:- op( 1055, xfx, <:> ).
:- op( 1053, xfx, && ).
:- op( 1052, xfx, ::- ).
:- op( 1051, xfx, from ).

translate_rule( (LP::=[]<:>Sem), H ) :-
    !,
    t_lp( LP, [], S, S, Sem, H ).
translate_rule( (LP::=[]), H ) :-
    !,
    t_lp( LP, [], S, S, [], H ).
translate_rule( (LP::=RP<:>Sem), (H:-B) ) :-
    !,
    t_rp( RP, [], StL, S, SR, B1 ),
    reverse( StL, RStL ),
    t_lp( LP, RStL, S, SR, Sem, H ),
    tidy( B1, B ).
translate_rule( (LP::=RP), (H:-B) ) :-
    translate_rule( (LP::=RP<:>[]), (H:-B) ).


t_lp( (LP,List), StL, S, SR, Sem, H ) :-
    append( List, SR, List2 ),
    makelist( Sem, Semantics ),
    add_extra_args( [node(LP,StL,Semantics),S,List2], LP, H ).
t_lp( LP, StL, S, SR, Sem, H ) :-
    makelist( Sem, Semantics ),
    add_extra_args( [node(LP,StL,Semantics),S,SR], LP, H ).


t_rp( !, St, St, S, S, ! ) :- !.
t_rp( [], St, [ [] | St ], S, S1, S=S1 ) :- !.
t_rp( [X], St, [ [X] | St ], S, SR, c(S,X,SR) ) :- !.
t_rp( [X|R], St, [ [X|R] | St ], S, SR, (c(S,X,SR1),RB) ) :-
    !,
    t_rp( R, St, [ R | St ], SR1, SR, RB ).
t_rp( {T}, St, St, S, S, T ) :- !.
t_rp( (T,R), St, StR, S, SR, (Tt,Rt) ) :-
    !,
    t_rp( T, St, St1, S, SR1, Tt ),
    t_rp( R, St1, StR, SR1, SR, Rt ).
t_rp( T^^N, St, [N|St], S, SR, Tt ) :-
    add_extra_args( [N,S,SR], T, Tt ).
t_rp( T, St, [St1|St], S, SR, Tt ) :-
    add_extra_args( [St1,S,SR], T, Tt ).


add_extra_args( L, T, T1 ) :-
    T =.. Tl,
    append( Tl, L, Tl1 ),
    T1 =.. Tl1.


tidy( ((P1,P2),P3), Q ) :-
    tidy( (P1,(P2,P3)), Q ).
tidy( (P1,P2), (Q1,Q2) ) :-
    !,
    tidy( P1, Q1 ),
    tidy( P2, Q2 ).
tidy( A, A ).


c( [X|S], X, S ).


makelist( Sem, [Sem] ) :-
    var( Sem ),
    !.
makelist( (Sem1&&Sem2), [Sem1_|List] ) :-
    !,
    makelist_1( Sem1, Sem1_ ),
    makelist_1( Sem2, Sem2_ ),
    makelist( Sem2_, List ).
makelist( [], [] ) :- !.
makelist( Sem, [Sem] ).


makelist_1( (Attr from Var), Sem ) :-
    !,
    Attr_V =.. [ Attr, _V ],
    Sem = (Attr_V ::- Var^^Attr_V).
makelist_1( Sem, Sem ).


node( _, _, Sem ) ^^ Args :-
    Sem ^^ Args.
[ (Args::-Traverse) | _Rules ] ^^ Args :-
    Traverse.
[ Args | _Rules ] ^^ Args.
[ _ | Rules ] ^^ Args :-
    Rules ^^ Args.

dctg_reconsult( File ) :-
    seeing( CIS ),
    see( File ), seen,
    see( File ),
    dctg_reconsult_1( '$none' ),
    seen,
    see( CIS ).


dctg_reconsult_1( Previous ) :-
    read( Term ),
    (
        Term = end_of_file
    ->
        true
    ;
        process_term( Term, Previous, Next ),
        dctg_reconsult_1( Next )
    ).


process_term( ?-(Term), _, '$none' ) :-
    call( Term ) -> true ; true.

process_term( :-(Term), _, '$none' ) :-
    call( Term ) -> true ; true.

process_term( DCTG, Previous, Next  ) :-
    ( DCTG = (_ ::= _) ; DCTG = (_ <:> _) ),
    !,
    translate_rule( DCTG, Prolog ),
    process_term( Prolog, Previous, Next ).

process_term( :-(Head,Tail), Previous, clause(Functor,Arity) ) :-
    !,
    functor( Head, Functor, Arity ),
    (
        Previous \= clause(Functor,Arity)
    ->
        abolish( Functor, Arity )
    ;
        true
    ),
    assert( (Head:-Tail) ).

process_term( Head, Previous, Next ) :-
    process_term( (Head:-true), Previous, Next ).
```

Comment: DCTGs are described in Abramson, Harvey, and Veronica Dahl. 1989. Logic Grammars. Symbolic Computation AI Series. Springer-Verlag, 1989.